# regex that ignore all inside <a> [url][img]

Tags: javascript

This is a tricky regex code, actually i have a script that works fine, but i need a more precise pattern to avoid conflict with url that contain hashtag and bbcode.

actually my code replace all hashtags words like #example and turn it into link like:

`https://myurl/?q=example`

so my regex is:

`const regex = /#[^\s!@#$%^&*()=+.\/,\[{\]};:'"?><]+/g;`

i want a regex that ignore all urls inside `<a>`, all url inside [url], and [img] to avoid bbcode conflict.

but i can't find a valid pattern

full code that i have actually:

```js
export default function () {

  const regex = /#[^\s!@#$%^&*()=+.\/,\[{\]};:'"?><]+/g;

  const p = this.$('.Post-body');
  const baseurl = app.forum.attribute('baseUrl');

  p.html = p.html(p.html().replace(regex, match => `<a href="${baseurl}/?q=${match}" class="hashlink" title="Find more post with this hashtag">${match}</a>`))

}
```

Comment: Hold up. This is BBCode, where the whole point is to _not_ allow HTML and only allow BBcodes exactly for this reason. Why are there `<a>` at all?

Comment: because if i post an url like `https://website.com`, this will become `<a href.....` automatically...and with my regex if the url contain an hashtag....my script will broke the link

Comment: Then you need to clarify what you're actually doing here, because the _post source_ has no `<a>`, but does have `[url]` and bare-string urls, whereas the _rendered_ post has no `[url]` or bare-string urls, but does have `a` elements that can be querySelected like everything else in the DOM. What are you actually doing, and to what?

Comment: Here the source code https://github.com/justoverclockl/flarum-ext-hashtag/blob/main/js/src/forum/ReplaceHashTag.js

Comment: This code actually works but I have problems with url that contain anchor tags, and bbcode…so I want to exclude these

Comment: As per the [posting guidelines](/help/how-to-ask): put your code in your post, in [mcve] form. External links should only be specified _in addition to_ the MCVE code you put in your post. Remember, you're asking people to help you: help them do that efficiently by having all the details relevant to your question in your post. Not off-site.

Comment: I do not have other code unfortunately, it’s a forum extension…I don’t know how to help u, I think my first post describe the problem

Comment: It can be a bit tricky to do. I would approach it like this: replace all shortcode to some sort of unique value, then do the same with all the links, then find all URLs and make them links, then replace your shortcode and links back in place of these placeholders. Does it make sense?

Comment: @RoboRobok could u please make an example?

Answer (score 0):

actually i've found a solution that works, i will post here the soution (could be useful for someone)

```
 const regex = /(?<!https?:\/\/\S*)#[^\s!@#$%^&*()=+.\/,\[{\]};:'"?><]+/g;
```

and i've removed the extra # using `match.slice`

Comment: There are billion cases where it won't work as expected.

Comment: unfortunately no one can help me here, so for now is the best i can do

Comment: I can help you, but can you tell me if you parse the shortcode first? You need these URLs replaced in the final output along with the shortcode? Or you do it on the fly just to display it? If you parse the shortcode first, then we only need convert text being an URL to a link, is that correct?

Comment: what i need now is that regex ignore all html link, and all bbcode [url][img]...here my actual code: https://pastebin.com/chFsBKgw

Comment: Why do you need the links to be parsed, but not the shortcode? Are you sure you're doing it right?

Comment: because in bbcode myabe someone could write url with anchor tag, or link that contain #, this will cause some issue...am i right?

Comment: Yes, but why wouldn't you parse your URLs after parsing the bbcode?

Comment: if this is possible would be great, simply i do not know how can i do this, so i would prevent any issue

Comment: i think i will drop this project, safari seems that is not compatible with this regexp, and i'm not able to find help on this. thanks to all by the way.

Comment: It really is unclear what you want to do. Why do you do it with JavaScript during render time instead of storing it?

Comment: This is trickier than it appears at the first glance. I think it would be best to iterate through all text nodes and check if they're not inside certain tags, such as `<a>`, `<script>` etc.